# How to find an element by href value using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have href value of an anchor tag which only have href value as attribute. Now I want to find the element in the page which have same value as my href value and click it. I am unable to find any way of doing this using standard selenium methods.How can I do this?
Basically these are the functions I found but it seems that I can't use any of these:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use find_element_by_xpath functionality.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+url+'"]')
```

Comment: What if I have my url in a variable?

Comment: than just add it as a string there.

Comment: keep in mind that you might get an array returned if you have more than one link with the same URL

Comment: This works very well, as long as the page has loaded all the contents

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"href")]')
```

Answer (score 7):

You would find the element by the CSS selector, as you would using vanilla CSS:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[href^=http://somelink.com/]')
```

You can also [find the element by the link text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html):

```
link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('somelink')
```

Answer (score 3):

When the button looks like

```
<a href="server_export.php" class="tab">&nbsp;Export</a>
```

and because possibly the text is translated, we cannot use the search for the text `Export`, so we have to search e.g. for `server_export` within the `href` and can e.g. click it with

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[contains(@href,"server_export")]').click()
```

Note: Using the recommended `find_element(By.xxxxx, ...)` format.

Answer (score 1):

I have a button called Your Profile with this html line

```
<a href="/registration/profile.html" rel="follow">Your Profile</a>
```

I have been trying everything so far find_element_by link, xpath, css selector with no luck. It returns error unable to find the element.

```
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Your Profile")

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"registration/profile.html")]')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In versions 4 and later of Selenium, use `find_element()` combined with a CSS selector and the `By` class:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

jobs_link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href='https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/?']")
jobs_link.click()
```